# Accessing protected components after a document becomes unprotected

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-2010

I'm looking to modify a document inside a DocumentOpen event, adding some content controls to existing text where appropriate and changing formatting. This works fine, but becomes more complicated when the DocumentOpen event fires after a protected document is unprotected:

### [image: word_protected]

Clicking "Enable Editing" begins the process of "unprotecting" a document, and the DocumentOpen event I've defined fires at this time. Because the event seems to fire before the default unprotected window is opened, however, creating a content control is still considered unavailable. A simple example that won't succeed when a document is in the process of being unprotected:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.DocumentOpen += application_DocumentOpen;
}

private void application_DocumentOpen(Document doc)
{
    doc.ContentControls.Add(
        WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText,
        doc.Range(doc.Content.Start, doc.Content.End - 1));
}
```

Is there some way to hurry the unprotection process along, so to speak, and still be able to execute my code? Or another event that predictably fires when document editing becomes available? I've looked at the events that are fired related to protected mode [in the Microsoft documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=microsoft_office_word&y=2010&m=09&d=13&WeblogPostName=object-model-considerations-for-protected-view-in-word-2010&GroupKeys=), but haven't seen anything that would suit my needs. `Document.Unprotect()` and changing `Document.ActiveWindow.View.Type` also are unfortunately not useful, as "Protected Mode" appears to be a totally different, uneditable, window. It's a requirement that these formatting modifications are made when the document is opened, or as quickly as possible thereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ain't pretty, but I ended up solving this problem by defining a delegate containing the code I want to execute, associated with a container for each document, and checking to see if the delegate can be executed inside `Application.WindowActivate`:

```
public class DocumentContainer
{
    public Action ProtectedDeferredExecution { get; set; }

    public DocumentContainer(Action deferred)
    {
        ProtectedDeferredExecution = deferred;
    }
}

public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Dictionary<Document, DocumentContainer> DocumentContainerDict { get; set; }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DocumentContainerDict = new Dictionary<Document, DocumentContainer>();
        Application.WindowActivate += application_WindowActivate;
        Application.DocumentOpen += application_DocumentOpen;
        Application.DocumentBeforeClose += application_DocumentClose;
    }

    private void application_DocumentOpen(Document doc)
    {
        // define code that is unsafe when document is protected
        Action initialization = () =>
        {
            doc.ContentControls.Add(
                WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText,
                doc.Range(doc.Content.Start, doc.Content.End - 1));
        };

        // if the current window isn't "protected", able to execute the unsafe code
        if (Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow == null)
        {
            initialization();
            initialization = null;
        }

        // send either the unsafe delegate or null to the constructor
        DocumentContainerDict.Add(doc, new VersioningDocumentContainer(initialization));
    }

    private void application_WindowActivate(Document doc, Window wn)
    {
        // skip execution if the window is still protected or isn't the view we want
        if (wn.View.Type != WdViewType.wdPrintView || Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        DocumentContainer container;

        // find the document container, if any, and the delegate to execute
        if (DocumentContainerDict.TryGetValue(doc, out container)
            && container.ProtectedDeferredExecution != null)
        {
            container.ProtectedDeferredExecution();
            container.ProtectedDeferredExecution = null;
        }
    }

    // clean up
    private void application_DocumentClose(Document doc, ref bool cancel)
    {
        DocumentContainerDict.Remove(doc);
    }
}
```

Other metadata could also easily be defined in this container (which is what I use it for), so I create one for every document that is created with the add-in.